# mixing two different types of solar panels with different wattage

Tags: voltage, current, solar-cell

I have two solar panels (( Poly-100w(5.6A) - Mono-50w(2.6A) )) both have a voltage PmaX of 17-18v.

I want to connect the both of them in parallel and then insert them into a 10A solar charger.

Will I have any problem doing so, and will I have any reduction of the current in this state? please Help.

Answer (score 1):

In some ways, parallel/series combination of PV panels is very similar to doind the same with batteries. To combine panels effectively/efficiently:

- Combining PV panels in *parallel* requires you to use panels with the same/very close voltages.
- Combining PV panels in *series* requires you to use panels with the same/very close currents.

Since you are wanting to combine panels of differing currents, but the same rated max. voltage, in parallel, you should be able to achieve a fair amoint of efficiency.

One safeguard that I would *highly* recommend is that you add a diode in series with each panel. While they *are* rated for the same Vmax, differing illumination (i.e. shadows) and/or manufacturing tolerances could easily cause a situation where one panel would attempt to backfeed power through the other one.

PV panels have quite a reputation for being easily damaged by backfeeding, so it is important that you safeguard them from damaginf each other that way.